# why can't I pass my list into python class in the below implementation of Last In First out(LIFO)

Tags: python, list, class

I must use a class to pass this list and implement LIFO.

```
class Sclass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.lst = []
    def sadd(self,lst,a):
        print "before append" self.lst
        self.lst.append(a)
        print "post append" self.lst
        return lst

    def sretrieve(self,lst):
        self.lst.pop(-1)

my_list=Sclass()
lt=my_list.sadd(12)
print lt
```

How do I add multiple values into the list and then retrieve them until the whole list is empty

Comment: `Sclass` has it's own list, and the `sadd` method expects a list and something else to be passed to the method. In your use case, you did not pass a list to the `sadd` method which is probably where all the confusion is coming from

Comment: see official document https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists

Comment: Could you help me resolve this . I want to implement LIFO using classes and python lists. The Class should have all the methods like add and retrieve which normally do on a list.

Comment: You don't need to write a class for a stack. Firstly, you could use a general-purpose Python list. Secondly, I believe Python has special containers for LIFO (and FIFO and others) that should be easy to find using a websearch.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a very simple example.

```
class LifoContainer(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.lst = []

    def push(self, item):
        self.lst.append(item)

    def pop(self):
        return self.lst.pop()

container = LifoContainer()
container.push(3)
container.push(4)
container.push(5)

assert container.pop() == 5
assert container.pop() == 4
assert container.pop() == 3
```